# Ionic 2 changing card text color

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been trying to use ion-cards using ion dark theme, and I can't actually see the text;

[image]

I tried to change the CSS with this:

```
  h2,p {
    color:white;
  }
```

and it's still black.

I took the code right from ionic documentation:

```
<ion-card class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let new of news;let i=index">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img [src]="new.image_url" *ngIf="new.image_url">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
    <p>AA TEST</p>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-card-content>
    <p>
    TSET SUMMARY
    </p>
    </ion-card-content>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button icon-left clear small>
        <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
        <div>12 likes</div>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-card>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try with `!important`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite the ionic variable itself. Navigate the ./theme/variables.scss and add

```
$card-ios-text-color(#fff);
$card-md-text-color(#fff);
$card-wp-text-color(#fff);
```

All the ionic variables can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) for quick reference